# HTML text input conditional submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a page that loads a random MP3 file on each refresh. The user has to guess a name based on the sound via text form input. I want to check their input against the stored string and refresh the page if it's correct. Otherwise, I wan't to give them an incorrect alert and stay on the same page so they can guess again:

```
<div class="ui-widget" align="center">
<form method="post" action="" class="answer_box" onsubmit="return submit();">
    <p>Which hero is it?  <input id="tags" name="guess"  /></p>
    <script>
        var key = <?php echo json_encode($rand_key) ?>;
        var info = document.getElementById("guess").value;

        function submit() {
            if (key==info){
                alert('Correct!');
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert('Incorrect!');
                returnToPreviousPage();
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>

</form>
</div>
```

Right now, it submits the information to a new page regardless of the input. The javascript alerts are also not showing (I suspect they do show, but the page then refreshes and they disappear). The key variable is the key from the randomly taken value of a PHP array, and info should be the text the user inputs.

Comment: Not a very safe approach to be honest, they could just open up the script and see the key right there.

Comment: can you provide the contents of `$rand_key` ?

Comment: Show us `var_dump(json_encode($rand_key));` result. Did you try to trigger that JS via button input, instead of form? Seems a better approach (regardless of @MinusFour comment, which should be also considered)

Comment: @CodeGodie: AFAIK, `submit` is a method of a HtmlForm object, used as in `document.forms[0].submit();`.

Comment: @JoelAlejandro thanks for the breakdown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problems found:

1. you cant use `submit` as a function name a this is an HtmlForm object
2. `document.getElementById("guess").value;` is looking for an element with ID of "guess" and that does not exist.

I would rewrite your script like this:

```
<script>
    var key = <?php echo json_encode($rand_key) ?>;

    function my_submit(curr) {
        var info = curr.guess.value;
        if (key == info) {
            alert('Correct!');
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert('Incorrect!');
            returnToPreviousPage();
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<form onsubmit="return my_submit(this);">
    <p>Which hero is it? <input id="tags" name="guess"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: CodeGodie, since `submit` is precisely part of the HtmlForm object, it can be used as a JS global, it doesn't conflict with any other functions.

Comment: You can easily check this by opening F12 here and typing `window.submit` or `submit`. You'll get `undefined` in both cases.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I replaced returnToPreviousPage() with event.preventDefault() as well, and it works exactly like it should. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem here:

`<input id="tags" name="guess"  />`

Your `id` is `tags`, not `guess`.

You should use `document.getElementById("tags").value`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to retrieve the value of an element with id of "guess." Change this to "tags."

```
var info = document.getElementById("tags").value;
```

Also, as @CodeGodie mentioned, you need to change your function name to something other than submit.